# Bind on change and other actions to multiple ajax loaded elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, events

I have a form which has multiple inputs, selects and textareas.

On load jQuery finds every element, sets its data-attr to default value, binds an on change event to it and triggers a change.

Problem is, that some selects are being re-loaded with ajax based on other input values.

Is there a simple way to change this code, to work on ajax loaded elements?
It has to set the initial data-attr value, but only once per element (after it appears in dom), same with triggering the change.

This is the original code:

```
$main_form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-empty', 'true').off('change').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('number')) validate_int($(this));
        update_progress($(this));
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

I know there is something like:

```
$main_form.on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){

});
```

But that would bind the data-attr on every change and it would also infinitely trigger the change. Also, the `.off('change')` is not really, needed there, I am just used to use it.

I do not want to copy this code and add it to ajax done function, as I am trying to prevent duplication of code, which would make maintaining and adjusting it harder than it already is. Or is that the only option?

.

If you have any questions, just comment and I will update my answer to be as precise as it possibly could.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Would making that routine a function, calling it once on pageload, and calling it after every successful response work?

Comment: I have it as a function with some more items in there, problem is, you cant call this multiple times, as it would reset the `data-empty` attribute and trigger the change on all elements after single element has been loaded with ajax. And I am also trying to prevent code duplication by not calling it in ajax `done` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to set an initial value for `data-empty` attribute and trigger a change event once for every loaded, and *future loaded* form element.

I would suggest that you use event delegation for the part of code that must be executed on every `change` event occurrence:

```
// This will affect all form element (including those loaded with ajax)
$main_form.on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('number')) validate_int($(this));
    update_progress($(this));
});
```

Create a function that performs initial assignment of values:

```
/**
*  Set initial value and trigger change event
*  @param $elem {jQuery object} The target element
*/
function setInitialValue($elem) {
   $elem.attr('data-empty', 'true').trigger('change');
}
```

And set initial data attribute and trigger a `change` event on every ajax successful callback:

```
success: function(data) {
   var targetElement = $('select');
   targetElement .append(data);
   setInitialValue(targetElement);
}
```

Finally, you can trigger a change event for every initialy loaded element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $main_form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
        setInitialValue($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, so basically what I kinda tried to avoid (but in nicer package split to functions so code is not actually duplicated :P). So there is no way to do this with single code similar to what I have? :(

Comment: I can't think of anything else right now! I'll let you know if somthing new come to my mind! :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Its for work so I tried to make the code really clean and easy to maintain, that's why I didn't go with your approach right away myself. But if nobody is able to find a better solution, I'll accept it tomorrow as I implement it to the code :P